# Select from several tables with fix count rows in relative table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: threads and members.

Table threads:  id | name | ...

Table members:   id | threadId | name | ...

Thread can have 2 or more members. Member can exists in different threads.
I want get one thread, which have only 2 members and one of this members have name AAA.

DB: sqlite in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select m.ThreadId
from members m
group by m.ThreadId
having count(*) = 2 and
       sum(case when m.name = 'AAA' then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```